# Substituir conjunto de palavras no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Eu tenho uma planilha Excel com algumas colunas, por exemplo:

```
Fruta | Veículo | Profissões
--------------------------

Banana   Carro   Médico
Pera     Moto    Programador
Maça     Barco   Engenheiro
Morango  Avião   Advogado
```

E em outra coluna...

```
Coluna 1
--------
Banana
Pera
Carro
Médico
```

E gostaria que essa coluna se transformasse em:

```
Coluna 1
--------
Fruta
Fruta
Veículo
Profissão
```

Como eu poderia realizar essa substituição automatizada de vários dados da planilha?

*obs.: Não importa a ferramenta ou linguagem de programação para realizar tal feito*

Comment: Mas você está a procura de uma formula ou de código VBA ?

Comment: Procuro a forma mais objetiva e sucinta, mas qualquer ajuda é válida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível definir uma função que faça essa busca e retorne o título da coluna, que é o nome de cada grupo. Abaixo um exemplo funcional, com base nos dados da pergunta:

### Definindo a function VBA

A função abaixo irá receber o valor procurado e um intervalo de colunas, a partir disso ela faz um loop em cada coluna, pesquisando o valor procurado. Ao localizar (ou não), ela encerra e retorna o resultado. Está com comentários para mais entendimento:

```
Public Function ProcMultiplasColunas(ByVal ValorProcurado As String, ByVal RangeColunas As Range) As String

Dim ColunaLoop As Long
Dim ColunaLocalizada As String
Dim Corresp As Variant

ColunaLocalizada = ""

For ColunaLoop = 1 To RangeColunas.Columns.Count Step 1

    'Usa função nativa de corresp(match)
    Corresp = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Corresp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ValorProcurado, RangeColunas.Columns(ColunaLoop), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Verifica se localizou, seta a coluna e encerra For
    If Corresp <> 0 Then
        ColunaLocalizada = RangeColunas.Cells(1, ColunaLoop)
        Exit For
    End If

Next ColunaLoop

'Testa se localizou algum valor e encerra a função
If ColunaLocalizada = "" Then
    ProcMultiplasColunas = "#NÃO LOCALIZADO!"
Else
    ProcMultiplasColunas = ColunaLocalizada 'retorna a coluna localizada para a função
End If

End Function
```

Esse procedimento retorna o resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Sub para substituir conteúdos

Precisamos que o processo execute linha a linha, isso foi definido a partir de um For, que aplica a function definida anteriormente. Ela sobrescreve o conteúdo da célula em análise. Está com comentários para mais entendimento:

```
Sub substituiValores()

Dim linha As Integer 'declara a linha como inteiro

For linha = 2 To 5 'verificará da linha 2 até a 5 - precisa ajustar ou aprimorar
    If Cells(linha, 1) <> "" Then 'verifica se tem conteúdo na célula e executa a fórmula
        Cells(linha, 1) = ProcMultiplasColunas(Cells(linha, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha2").Range("A:C"))
    End If 'fecha if
Next linha 'próxima linha, se não foi encerrado no if verdadeiro

End Sub
```

### Pontos de atenção

1. Pode ter problemas de performance, dependendo da máquina e tamanho das bases;
2. As executar a sub, os valores originais são perdidos, sem recuperar ou "desfazer (ctrl z)". Repare que está definido para ele deixar um "#NÃO LOCALIZADO!", porém, fica impossível de saber qual foi o conteúdo original não localizado (uma vez que sobrescreveu).
3. Esse não é o único caminho. Existem outros meios de contornar essa necessidade, como reorganizar a base de grupos (título e lista). Se ela for reorganizada (se possível), uma simples função de procv atenderia, por exemplo. Outra possibilidade talvez exista com definições matriciais (fórmulas "Ctrl-Shift-Enter" ou "CSE"), somente como exemplo também.